# RegEx to match whole line after nth occurrence of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Long time lurker, first time poster! Thanks to anyone in advance that can help.

I'm using Node.JS and Electron to make a little desktop app that manages the values in a game file (which is from a custom file type, basically a glorified INI file). With the idea of letting people customise the file in a nice UI as opposed to combing through hundreds of lines of code. Below is a sample from the file:

```
setting $Low
    prop $Config A_STRING_HERE "5, 10, 15, 20"

setting $Medium
    prop $Config A_STRING_HERE "10, 20, 40, 80"

setting $High
    prop $Config A_STRING_HERE "20, 40, 80, 160"

setting $VeryHigh
    prop $Config A_STRING_HERE "40, 80, 160, 320"
```

How would I go about matching, for example, the "setting $High" (3rd) occurrence containing "A_STRING_HERE" until the end of the line. I'm hoping to match just:

`A_STRING_HERE "20, 40, 80, 160"`.

The values are dynamic and will change a lot, so matching the line with the values isn't necessarily an option.

- `\A_STRING_HERE.+\g` will match all the occurrences to the end of the line.
- `\A_STRING_HERE.+\` will match the first occurrence to the end of the line.
- `\A_STRING_HERE.+\??????` will match the 3rd occurrence to end of the line?

Thanks again and all the best!

Comment: Title actually contains two questions: 1) Which RegExp can do X 2) How to do X. I would go with 2) only, 1) is just one possible method. Also, the question is not really specific to Node.js & Electron, so I would remove that from the title.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the second part from the title as the first part is more what I'm interested in. A simple regular expression would solve my problem a lot more easily than having to refactor everything -- I am open to whatever solution though as I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days now. Although at this point I'm about ready to just have a JS Object to match the values to -- then the regular expression can match the string along with the associated values which would let me target a specific line

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question given the file data you're showing: are you asking for repetition of a string _in a line_ or _in the entire file_ (i.e. across multiple lines). And to make that clearer, can you update your post with a concrete example? Given real file content, and given "what need", what result are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks I've reformatted the entire question. I basically just want to match a specific occurrence. The file is hundreds of lines of config that the game references on start up, the sample I provided is ripped directly from the file and I changed the "A_STRING_HERE" to make it clear what I was hoping to target. I'm not sure I'm allowed to attach the file here as it's not my work, it belongs to EA.

Comment: What (besides it being the third line) sets it apart from the other lines? Or are you going  find lines by position?

Comment: @zer00ne nothing other than the preceding line being Low/Medium/High/VeryHigh

Comment: @Mandy8055 OMG you genius! Yeah this is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! I would never have gotten to this by myself

Comment: @zer00ne yeah it's definitely a separate line, `setting $High` is. a different line from `prop $Config A_STRING_HERE "20, 40, 80, 160"`

Although @Mandy8055 just provided me with a regular expression that matches

Comment: @Simp4Code I was going to do look ahead instead of look behind thinking that the setting was a second value not the first one.

Comment: @zer00ne ahhh, I see what you mean about the wrapping now! As for the look ahead / look behind -- no idea what this means, I really need to take the time to learn RegEx. I've never had to do something this complicated, it's usually a simple expression for simple form validation

Comment: @Mandy8055 thanks, I tried my best to work it into the question. Hoping it still makes sense. I've edited this question like 10 times already -- it's a difficult issue to put into words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably try this regex:

```
(?<=setting \$High\n\s*?prop \$Config )A_STRING_HERE.*
```

**Explantion**

- **`(?<=)`** - Represents **[positive lookbehind.](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#compound)**
- **`setting \$High\n\s*?prop \$Config`** - The text that separates this match with other matches. You can probably omit `setting`  part to make it more concise.

  - **`\n`** - Represents new line.
  - **`\s*?`** - **Lazily** matches 0 or more white spaces. You can adjust it according to your need.
- **`.*`** - Matches everything except `\n`. You can be specific here as well if you want to include numbers only.
- **`\g`** - Please note only global flag is used.

You can find the implementation of the above regex in **[here.](https://regex101.com/r/WG4Fip/1)**

**Image Explanation:**
[image]

```js
const regex = /(?<=setting \$High\n\s*?prop \$Config )A_STRING_HERE.*/g;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(?<=setting \\$High\\n\\s*?prop \\$Config )A_STRING_HERE.*', 'g')

const str = `setting \$Low
    prop \$Config A_STRING_HERE "5, 10, 15, 20"
setting \$Medium
    prop \$Config A_STRING_HERE "10, 20, 40, 80"
setting \$High
    prop \$Config A_STRING_HERE "20, 40, 80, 160"
setting \$VeryHigh
    prop \$Config A_STRING_HERE "40, 80, 160, 320"`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! I've been wrestling with this for a couple days in RegEx editors, I would have never gotten to your solution. I was on a much different path trying all sorts that wasn't working. You're amazing! Thank you very much!

I'm too new to upvote your answer but I have accepted it as the solution! You deserve 100+

Comment: How did you make that image? It's sick.

Comment: @Mandy8055 since you were so incredibly helpful last time I was wondering if you would be able to help me with a very similar problem. See the RegEx here https://regex101.com/r/U6ItoQ/1 -- I basically want to do the same match but this time the string is 2 lines below. So I need to match "ANOTHER_STRING_HERE" -- I tried fiddling with some of the parameters but wasn't able to get it matching. Thank you in advance

Comment: Actually, I figured this out `(?<=setting \$Low\n[\s\S]*?prop \$ConfigGroup ) ANOTHER_STRING_HERE.*` without the global flag works perfectly!